# Assets in NextJS public folder respond with 404 for .** filenames

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, static-files, applepay

I am able to serve static files in my public folder successfully, but this doesn't work for files with a leading dot in their filename (.**).

I'm looking to host the "well-known" text file for apple-pay domain verification and this file must start with a dot `.well-known-apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt`. As a result, I keep getting a 404 when I try to access the file path in my browser.

If I remove the leading dot, the file becomes accessible. Are there any workarounds to this?

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation, but I'm assuming that Next.js by default doesn't serve "hidden" files that start with `.`. You could try making a GET route that serves it in the meantime...

Comment: You can also configure nginx or something else to serve the public directory instead of next doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder .well-known and put your file in there. Next will host it at {host}/.well-known/blah.txt

`mkdir ./public/.well-known`

`cp apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt ./public/.well-known`